# Strange behavior: Scala Actors 2.7.7 vs. 2.8-Snapshot

Tags: scala, concurrency, scala-2.8, actor, scala-2.7

I'm an 18 years old trainee and I'm discovering scala which I like very much :-).
To get familiar with the scala actors I wrote a small simulation with some gears and one controller. The ActorApplication creates N gears with random speed. The controller calculates a synchronization speed and starts the gear-actors. The gears synchronize to this given speed step by step (1+ or 1-). The simulation is finished when all gears have reached the synchronization speed.
I developed the simulation in scala 2.7.7 - and it worked as I expected it (see output below). However, when I swichted to the current 2.8.0-SNAPSHOT I discovered strange behavior. 
This is the code:

```
/**
 * Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: pmei
 */
import actors.Actor
import actors.Actor._
import collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import java.util.Random

case class ReceivedSpeed(gear: Gear)
case class StartSync

case class SyncGear(controller: GearController, syncSpeed: Int)

object ActorApplication extends Application {
  private val random = new Random() //scala.util random won't be random :(

  println("[App] start with creating gears")
  val gearList = new ListBuffer[Gear]()
  for (i <- 0 until 100) {
    gearList += new Gear(i)
  }

  val gearController = new GearController(gearList)

  gearController.start()
  gearController ! StartSync()
}

/**
 * CONTROLLER
 */
class GearController(nGears: ListBuffer[Gear]) extends Actor {

  private var syncGears = new ListBuffer[Gear]
  private var syncSpeed = 0
  def act = {
    loop {
      react {
        case StartSync() => {
          println("[Controller] Send commands for syncing to gears!")
          var speeds = new ListBuffer[Int]
          nGears.foreach(e => speeds += e.speed)

          //Calc avg
          //var avgSpeed = speeds.foldLeft(0)(_ + _) / speeds.length
          //var avgSpeed = speeds.foldLeft(0) { (x, y) => x + y } / speeds.length
          syncSpeed = (0/:speeds)(_ + _) / speeds.length //Average over all gear speeds

          println("[Controller] calculated syncSpeed: "+syncSpeed)
          nGears.foreach{e =>
                         e.start()
                         e ! SyncGear(this, syncSpeed)
          }
          println("[Controller] started all gears")
        }
        case ReceivedSpeed(gear: Gear) => {
          println("[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear ("+gear.gearId+")")
          //println("[Controller] mailboxsize: "+self.mailboxSize)
          syncGears += gear
          if(syncGears.length == nGears.length) {
            println("[Controller] all gears are back in town!")
            System.exit(0)
          }
        }
        case _ => println("[Controller] No match :(")
      }
    }
  }
}

/**
 * GEAR
 */
class Gear(id: Int) extends Actor {

  private val random = new Random() //scala.util random won't be random :(
  private var mySpeed = random.nextInt(1000)
  private var myController: GearController = null

  def speed = mySpeed
  def gearId = id

  println("[Gear ("+id+")] created with speed: "+mySpeed)

  def act = {
    loop {
      react {
        case SyncGear(controller: GearController, syncSpeed: Int) => {
          //println("[Gear ("+id+")] activated, try to follow controller command (form mySpeed ("+mySpeed+") to syncspeed ("+syncSpeed+")")
          myController = controller
          adjustSpeedTo(syncSpeed)
        }
      }
    }
  }

  def adjustSpeedTo(targetSpeed: Int) = {
    if(targetSpeed > mySpeed) {
      mySpeed += 1
      self ! SyncGear(myController, targetSpeed)
    }else if(targetSpeed < mySpeed) {
      mySpeed -= 1
      self ! SyncGear(myController, targetSpeed)
    } else if(targetSpeed == mySpeed) {
      callController
    }
  }

  def callController = {
    println("[Gear ("+id+")] has syncSpeed")
    myController ! ReceivedSpeed(this)
  }
}
```

The code above generates in scala 2.7.7 an output like:

```
[App] start with creating gears
[Gear (0)] created with speed: 935
[Gear (1)] created with speed: 398
[Gear (2)] created with speed: 164
[Gear (3)] created with speed: 64
[Gear (4)] created with speed: 461
[Gear (5)] created with speed: 741
[Gear (6)] created with speed: 93
[Gear (7)] created with speed: 850
[Gear (8)] created with speed: 679
[Gear (9)] created with speed: 587
[Gear (10)] created with speed: 789
[Gear (11)] created with speed: 849
[Gear (12)] created with speed: 386
[Gear (13)] created with speed: 981
[Gear (14)] created with speed: 246
[Gear (15)] created with speed: 661
[Gear (16)] created with speed: 245
[Gear (17)] created with speed: 655
[Gear (18)] created with speed: 193
[Gear (19)] created with speed: 240
[Gear (20)] created with speed: 72
[Gear (21)] created with speed: 884
[Gear (22)] created with speed: 334
[Gear (23)] created with speed: 169
[Gear (24)] created with speed: 665
[Gear (25)] created with speed: 773
[Gear (26)] created with speed: 333
[Gear (27)] created with speed: 524
[Gear (28)] created with speed: 673
[Gear (29)] created with speed: 189
[Gear (30)] created with speed: 573
[Gear (31)] created with speed: 762
[Gear (32)] created with speed: 162
[Gear (33)] created with speed: 735
[Gear (34)] created with speed: 222
[Gear (35)] created with speed: 854
[Gear (36)] created with speed: 124
[Gear (37)] created with speed: 650
[Gear (38)] created with speed: 514
[Gear (39)] created with speed: 0
[Gear (40)] created with speed: 106
[Gear (41)] created with speed: 117
[Gear (42)] created with speed: 912
[Gear (43)] created with speed: 782
[Gear (44)] created with speed: 161
[Gear (45)] created with speed: 748
[Gear (46)] created with speed: 311
[Gear (47)] created with speed: 168
[Gear (48)] created with speed: 776
[Gear (49)] created with speed: 424
[Gear (50)] created with speed: 749
[Gear (51)] created with speed: 819
[Gear (52)] created with speed: 664
[Gear (53)] created with speed: 996
[Gear (54)] created with speed: 877
[Gear (55)] created with speed: 808
[Gear (56)] created with speed: 781
[Gear (57)] created with speed: 464
[Gear (58)] created with speed: 408
[Gear (59)] created with speed: 337
[Gear (60)] created with speed: 822
[Gear (61)] created with speed: 812
[Gear (62)] created with speed: 979
[Gear (63)] created with speed: 290
[Gear (64)] created with speed: 972
[Gear (65)] created with speed: 20
[Gear (66)] created with speed: 787
[Gear (67)] created with speed: 680
[Gear (68)] created with speed: 466
[Gear (69)] created with speed: 554
[Gear (70)] created with speed: 53
[Gear (71)] created with speed: 212
[Gear (72)] created with speed: 90
[Gear (73)] created with speed: 535
[Gear (74)] created with speed: 268
[Gear (75)] created with speed: 893
[Gear (76)] created with speed: 847
[Gear (77)] created with speed: 671
[Gear (78)] created with speed: 106
[Gear (79)] created with speed: 779
[Gear (80)] created with speed: 433
[Gear (81)] created with speed: 757
[Gear (82)] created with speed: 400
[Gear (83)] created with speed: 88
[Gear (84)] created with speed: 89
[Gear (85)] created with speed: 348
[Gear (86)] created with speed: 695
[Gear (87)] created with speed: 618
[Gear (88)] created with speed: 986
[Gear (89)] created with speed: 624
[Gear (90)] created with speed: 578
[Gear (91)] created with speed: 613
[Gear (92)] created with speed: 52
[Gear (93)] created with speed: 9
[Gear (94)] created with speed: 91
[Gear (95)] created with speed: 790
[Gear (96)] created with speed: 481
[Gear (97)] created with speed: 443
[Gear (98)] created with speed: 709
[Gear (99)] created with speed: 772
[Controller] Send commands for syncing to gears!
[Controller] calculated syncSpeed: 512
[Controller] started all gears
[Gear (38)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (38)
[Gear (27)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (27)
[Gear (73)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (73)
[Gear (96)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (96)
[Gear (69)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (69)
[Gear (68)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (68)
[Gear (57)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (57)
[Gear (4)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (4)
[Gear (30)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (30)
[Gear (90)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (90)
[Gear (97)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (97)
[Gear (9)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (9)
[Gear (80)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (80)
[Gear (49)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (49)
[Gear (91)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (91)
[Gear (58)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (58)
[Gear (87)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (87)
[Gear (82)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (89)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (82)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (89)
[Gear (1)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (1)
[Gear (12)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (12)
[Gear (37)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (37)
[Gear (17)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (17)
[Gear (24)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (24)
[Gear (52)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (52)
[Gear (77)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (77)
[Gear (28)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (28)
[Gear (85)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (85)
[Gear (8)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (8)
[Gear (15)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (67)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (15)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (67)
[Gear (59)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (59)
[Gear (86)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (86)
[Gear (98)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (98)
[Gear (46)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (46)
[Gear (26)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (26)
[Gear (63)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (22)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (63)
[Gear (5)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (22)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (5)
[Gear (45)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (45)
[Gear (74)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (50)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (74)
[Gear (81)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (50)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (81)
[Gear (33)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (33)
[Gear (99)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (99)
[Gear (25)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (25)
[Gear (48)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (48)
[Gear (14)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (14)
[Gear (16)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (79)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (16)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (79)
[Gear (56)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (56)
[Gear (43)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (43)
[Gear (19)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (19)
[Gear (66)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (10)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (66)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (10)
[Gear (31)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (31)
[Gear (55)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (95)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (55)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (95)
[Gear (61)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (61)
[Gear (51)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (51)
[Gear (60)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (60)
[Gear (29)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (29)
[Gear (34)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (34)
[Gear (7)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (7)
[Gear (11)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (11)
[Gear (47)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (47)
[Gear (71)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (71)
[Gear (23)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (23)
[Gear (35)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (2)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (35)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (2)
[Gear (54)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (54)
[Gear (32)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (32)
[Gear (21)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (21)
[Gear (44)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (44)
[Gear (75)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (75)
[Gear (36)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (36)
[Gear (18)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (76)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (76)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (18)
[Gear (41)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (41)
[Gear (78)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (40)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (78)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (40)
[Gear (42)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (6)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (42)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (6)
[Gear (94)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (94)
[Gear (0)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (84)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (0)
[Gear (83)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (83)
[Gear (72)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (72)
[Gear (20)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (20)
[Gear (92)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (84)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (92)
[Gear (13)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (3)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (13)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (3)
[Gear (70)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (70)
[Gear (88)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (88)
[Gear (53)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (64)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (62)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (93)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (39)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (65)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (53)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (64)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (62)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (93)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (39)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (65)
[Controller] all gears are back in town!
```

You can see an **alternating** output of the different actors (gears and controller). But if I change to scala 2.8 I get an output like this:

```
[App] start with creating gears
[Gear (0)] created with speed: 995
[Gear (1)] created with speed: 40
[Gear (2)] created with speed: 483
[Gear (3)] created with speed: 920
[Gear (4)] created with speed: 339
[Gear (5)] created with speed: 422
[Gear (6)] created with speed: 258
[Gear (7)] created with speed: 603
[Gear (8)] created with speed: 40
[Gear (9)] created with speed: 399
[Gear (10)] created with speed: 347
[Gear (11)] created with speed: 339
[Gear (12)] created with speed: 559
[Gear (13)] created with speed: 697
[Gear (14)] created with speed: 18
[Gear (15)] created with speed: 568
[Gear (16)] created with speed: 271
[Gear (17)] created with speed: 239
[Gear (18)] created with speed: 889
[Gear (19)] created with speed: 933
[Gear (20)] created with speed: 793
[Gear (21)] created with speed: 494
[Gear (22)] created with speed: 683
[Gear (23)] created with speed: 41
[Gear (24)] created with speed: 738
[Gear (25)] created with speed: 291
[Gear (26)] created with speed: 833
[Gear (27)] created with speed: 610
[Gear (28)] created with speed: 514
[Gear (29)] created with speed: 793
[Gear (30)] created with speed: 917
[Gear (31)] created with speed: 838
[Gear (32)] created with speed: 801
[Gear (33)] created with speed: 153
[Gear (34)] created with speed: 19
[Gear (35)] created with speed: 549
[Gear (36)] created with speed: 524
[Gear (37)] created with speed: 912
[Gear (38)] created with speed: 517
[Gear (39)] created with speed: 586
[Gear (40)] created with speed: 662
[Gear (41)] created with speed: 143
[Gear (42)] created with speed: 147
[Gear (43)] created with speed: 445
[Gear (44)] created with speed: 1
[Gear (45)] created with speed: 366
[Gear (46)] created with speed: 397
[Gear (47)] created with speed: 523
[Gear (48)] created with speed: 920
[Gear (49)] created with speed: 91
[Gear (50)] created with speed: 316
[Gear (51)] created with speed: 573
[Gear (52)] created with speed: 956
[Gear (53)] created with speed: 615
[Gear (54)] created with speed: 636
[Gear (55)] created with speed: 385
[Gear (56)] created with speed: 422
[Gear (57)] created with speed: 574
[Gear (58)] created with speed: 882
[Gear (59)] created with speed: 274
[Gear (60)] created with speed: 371
[Gear (61)] created with speed: 971
[Gear (62)] created with speed: 999
[Gear (63)] created with speed: 990
[Gear (64)] created with speed: 367
[Gear (65)] created with speed: 646
[Gear (66)] created with speed: 957
[Gear (67)] created with speed: 187
[Gear (68)] created with speed: 432
[Gear (69)] created with speed: 472
[Gear (70)] created with speed: 899
[Gear (71)] created with speed: 325
[Gear (72)] created with speed: 615
[Gear (73)] created with speed: 315
[Gear (74)] created with speed: 425
[Gear (75)] created with speed: 441
[Gear (76)] created with speed: 679
[Gear (77)] created with speed: 125
[Gear (78)] created with speed: 706
[Gear (79)] created with speed: 455
[Gear (80)] created with speed: 15
[Gear (81)] created with speed: 155
[Gear (82)] created with speed: 669
[Gear (83)] created with speed: 590
[Gear (84)] created with speed: 457
[Gear (85)] created with speed: 574
[Gear (86)] created with speed: 1
[Gear (87)] created with speed: 472
[Gear (88)] created with speed: 763
[Gear (89)] created with speed: 329
[Gear (90)] created with speed: 385
[Gear (91)] created with speed: 176
[Gear (92)] created with speed: 674
[Gear (93)] created with speed: 528
[Gear (94)] created with speed: 702
[Gear (95)] created with speed: 328
[Gear (96)] created with speed: 82
[Gear (97)] created with speed: 833
[Gear (98)] created with speed: 101
[Gear (99)] created with speed: 950
[Controller] Send commands for syncing to gears!
[Controller] calculated syncSpeed: 504
[Controller] started all gears
[Gear (2)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (0)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (5)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (1)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (4)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (8)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (9)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (7)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (10)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (11)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (12)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (13)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (15)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (14)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (3)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (16)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (17)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (18)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (21)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (6)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (22)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (24)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (23)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (25)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (20)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (28)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (29)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (26)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (19)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (32)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (31)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (33)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (35)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (36)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (30)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (38)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (39)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (34)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (40)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (41)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (42)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (27)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (45)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (46)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (47)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (44)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (43)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (48)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (50)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (51)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (49)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (53)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (37)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (54)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (56)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (57)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (59)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (58)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (60)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (55)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (52)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (62)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (63)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (64)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (65)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (67)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (68)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (69)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (61)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (70)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (72)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (66)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (74)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (73)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (75)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (76)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (79)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (71)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (78)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (77)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (82)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (80)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (84)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (83)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (85)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (87)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (88)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (81)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (86)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (89)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (90)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (93)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (94)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (91)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (95)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (96)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (92)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (97)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (2)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (0)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (5)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (1)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (4)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (8)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (9)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (7)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (10)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (11)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (12)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (13)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (15)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (14)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (3)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (16)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (17)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (18)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (21)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (6)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (22)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (24)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (23)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (25)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (20)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (28)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (29)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (26)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (19)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (32)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (31)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (33)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (35)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (36)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (30)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (38)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (39)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (34)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (40)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (41)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (42)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (27)
[Gear (98)] has syncSpeed
[Gear (99)] has syncSpeed
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (45)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (46)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (47)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (44)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (43)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (48)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (50)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (51)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (49)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (53)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (37)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (54)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (56)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (57)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (59)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (58)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (60)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (55)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (52)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (62)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (63)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (64)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (65)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (67)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (68)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (69)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (61)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (70)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (72)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (66)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (74)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (73)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (75)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (76)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (79)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (71)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (78)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (77)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (82)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (80)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (84)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (83)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (85)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (87)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (88)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (81)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (86)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (89)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (90)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (93)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (94)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (91)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (95)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (96)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (92)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (97)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (98)
[Controller] Syncspeed received by a gear (99)
[Controller] all gears are back in town!
```

You can see that there is much less alternating actor-interactions. I suspect that the controller is blocked while the gears are working. Could someone explain this behavior? Thanks
Philipp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some problems with the code. Foremost among them, don't do this:

```
object ActorApplication extends Application
```

When you use `extends Application`, the way your code is run imposes a number of restrictions, such as not being optimizable by the JIT and, of particular relevance to your case, threads won't work correctly. I find it harder to explain what happened on 2.7.7 than what happened on 2.8. Instead, just write a normal object, and define the `main` method.

Other stuff:

```
gearController ! StartSync()
```

Don't do this. Always send a message to an actor from inside an actor, and this line is inside `ActorApplication` constructor, which is not an actor. In situations like this, you can do this:

```
Actor.actor { gearController ! StartSync() }
```

Speaking of `StartSync`, don't do this:

```
case class StartSync
```

A class without parameters is meaningless (and deprecated). Instead, do this:

```
case object StartSync
```

and drop the parenthesis after `StartSync` in the places where you use it.

Also, there's nothing wrong with `scala.util.Random`, though it was easier to misuse it on Scala 2.7 than it is on Scala 2.8, by creating a new `Random` generator every time you needed a random number (which is what you do in the code). Instead, on Scala 2.8, just this ought to work:

```
  private var mySpeed = scala.util.Random.nextInt(1000)
```

Finally, there's nothing wrong with either execution, it's just the scheduler that's different between them. In fact, given that you created a hundred actors, the `GearController` was receiving a disproportional amount of execution time in the Scala 2.7 version, as Scala doesn't create a thread for every actor.

Now, if you want `GearController` not to share a thread with the others, you should use `while(true)`/`receive` instead of `loop`/`react`, like this:

```
    while(true) {
      receive {
        case StartSync => {
```

Which will produce a result quite similar to what 2.7 produced.

Comment: Thank you Daniel for your helpful answer. I did the changes and my code runs well in Scala 2.8. I'll do a simple Scala-swing-GUI for this simulation and publish it on github.